# My wordpress child-theme doesn't apply css changes

Tags: wordpress

i've created a child theme from the nightingale theme but when I try to change a propetry in nigthingale-child/style.css it doesn't apply. For instance I've tried to change background-color of the body or display none for h1 markup just to see whether my child theme style.css works but nothing happens.

I've followed all steps for creating a child theme: 
-new folder nightingale-child
-inside this foder I've added two files : function.php & style.css
here is my style.css :

```
/*
 Theme Name: nightingale-child
 Theme URI:    http://example.com/twenty-fifteen-child/
 Description:  nightingale Child Theme
 Author:       John Doe
 Author URI:   http://example.com
 Template:     nightingale
 Version:      1.0.0
 License:      GNU General Public License v2 or later
 License URI:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 Tags:         light, dark, two-columns, right-sidebar, responsive-layout, accessibility-ready
 Text Domain:  nightingalechild
*/

a {
color: red;
}
```

---

---

and here is my function.php:

```
<?php 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_parent_styles' );

function enqueue_parent_styles() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
}
```

Does anybody know what's wrong with my nightingale-child theme ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is loading the PARENT theme CSS. You need to change a couple things to load the CHILD CSS:

```
<?php 
// Let's change this to `enqueue_child_styles` so it's clearer.
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_child_styles' );

// Now the function
function enqueue_child_styles() {
    // Rename the hook to child-style
   wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
}
```

In this instance, you want to use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` since `get_template_directory_uri()` always points to the PARENT theme, where as `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` points to the CHILD theme.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I also misnamed my function.php file : it's functions and not function. Otherwise the file is not recognize by wordpress.